# change the session id or invalidate the session and create new one?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

In the tomcat implementation, when session is invalidated and get the new one with this:

```
        oldSession.invalidate();
        HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
```

New session actually has the same session id as old one.  We do this when user logs in.  This is still vulnerable to session hijacking.  So, what I am thinking is that 
on the valve, old session is not invalidated, but new session id is assigned as below:

```
  public class SessionSecurityValue extends ValveBase {

   @Override
   public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    getNext().invoke(request, response);
        ManagerBase manager = (ManagerBase) request.getContext().getManager();
        manager.changeSessionId(request.getSessionInternal());
        request.changeSessionId(request.getSession().getId());
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("CHANGE_SESSION_ID");
   }
  }
```

Basically, I would like to understand security implications and risks when new session is created after invalidating old one, vs when session id of the old session is changed?

Thanks,

Comment: If instead you do  `oldSession.invalidate(); response.sendRedirect('otherpage'); return;` and let the session be created again on a different page, does it get a new session id?

Comment: Because if you are checking for a session hijack and think you detected one, I would think you would want to invalidate session and then redirect to the login page, not stay on same page and recreate session.

Comment: The new session ID is not the same as the old one. You have mis-observed it. That would be an obvious security breach and it would affect everyone. I've never seen it in over a decade of Tomcat use.

Comment: You know that Tomcat [already does this for you](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/04/25/session-fixation-protection), right? After a successful authentication, Tomcat changes the id of your session for you to prevent session-fixation attacks.